# Optimal number of Start-JobThread simultaneously

Tags: powershell

How do I calculate the optimal number of Powershell ThreadJobs? I have a script that hands out jobs to multiple servers but these servers do not have the same number of CPU cores and RAM always.
Is there some equation for dynamically calculating this optimal number to set as the ThrottleLimit?
The tasks are not very RAM or CPU intensive but it seems like powershell is always drastically slowing down when reaching above a thousand or so jobs.

Comment: test it on 2 systems with the same RAM but different CPU counts ... then test it on the reverse. once you have the data for that chunk of code on your systems, use it to calc the ratio you want to use. ///// the reason this is so VERY vague is that "it depends" is oh-so-very-true. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Such things can't easily be calculated. You have to tune it based on previous runs until it's (mostly) optimized.

Tuning consist of running a number a test setups with a set of config params that will affect the outcome and then deciding on the most effective one measured to use.

Comment: Can you please add some more description with your answer like some common practices for tuning.

Comment: Edit: Elaborated a bit on tuning methodology.